# Keep mobile browser top/bottom bars minimized unless user manually taps on them

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I'm creating a React web-app for which I have separate design on desktop screen sizes and mobile screen sizes. I have started working on mobile portion and came across a problem of mobile browser bars being in the way. Since they usually disappear when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up it would be acceptable but for some screens there is no scrollable content, hence there is no way for user to minimize those bars. 
I have tried using `.scrollTo()` 'hack' but it doesn't work either since there is no scrollable content. 
My question is if there is a way for me to minimize those and for them to come back to full size only after user taps on the remaining portion of those bars (for example, like safari does with **hide toolbar** option)